# Can an application bind on the intentService of another application, when the intent service is not started/running?

Tags: android, android-intentservice

The `IntentService` also has the `onBind` method. `BindService` call onto a non running service would start the service similarly would it do so for `IntentService`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

need to use an intent filter for service.

```
<service
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true"
                    android:name="de.vogella.android.ownservice.local.MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="de.vogella.android.ownservice.local.START_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

in calling app, we just need to add the line for getting service

```
Intent intent=new Intent("de.vogella.android.ownservice.local.START_SERVICE");  
                startService(intent);
```

i hope its useful to you..

Comment: You must not use intent filters with services and must call them with explicit intents only!